# finding equation polynomial of dataset excel

Tags: excel, equation

I have a set of xy data sets. Excel chart can plot a line of best fit as a polynomial. I need a function that can equate the line of best fit without going into the chart function and adding a trendline.

ie
[image]

the equation for this image is -0.0015x^2 + 0.575x + 130.14

I need the equation without the excel chart . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `LINEST()` worksheet function is written exactly for this purpose, hereby a link to some explanation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/linest-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d

Comment: brillaint Dominique, thank you !

Comment: In case my answer solves your issue, please upvote and/or accept it for reference purposes.